# Notepad++ replacing a word with a number in parens

Tags: replace, notepad++

Using `Notepad++`, how do I replace a word with a number within `()`?

For instance, replace the word `"serial"` with `"(1234)"`? When I try to do this, the word `"serial"` is replaced with `"1234"`, but without the parens.

Comment: In the replace dialog box what is the Search Mode set to?

Comment: Works fine for me. How exactly are you doing the search and replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In Notepad++ the parenthesis have to be escaped in the replacement part.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `serial`
- Replace with: `\(1234\)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choosing `Extended (\n,\r,\t,\0, \x...)` as the Search Mode and just specifying `(1234)` as the `Replace with` value worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Toto solves my problem.

In Notepad++ the parenthesis have to be escaped in the replacement part.

Ctrl+H
Find what: serial
Replace with: (1234)
CHECK Wrap around
CHECK Regular expression
Replace all

Comment: That's not how stackoverflow works. If an answer solves your problem, you may accept it, see: [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)